# How to Update a model by deleting it and again create it in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel. I need to know is there any easy way to update a model by delete the existing one and create it once more.

For example i have a login table contains id, username, password, userid and id.  When i try to update the username or password model i need to delete (soft delete) the entire row and create a new one with the updated values.  That means the data entered previously will not be changed. Is their any easy way in laravel like softdelete?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you'd just rollback your migration using the command:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Then update your migration with the columns you want to add, and then migrate it again using

```
php artisan migrate
```

If you need to add data to it as your table is created you can look into seeding:

http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#database-seeding

Also check out this link:

http://www.laravelsd.com/share/2nM4tV

It's a laravel schema designer, and you can customize your tables and export them as migrations and seed them using a GUI tool. It's pretty awesome!

EDIT: But to answer your main question, you can always export the current data in the table through phpmyadmin and import it back in once you migrate again. Though this would only work if you added columns to your table and have not modified the names of columns / removed any.

EDIT 2: Is this what your thinking of doing? Creating a new entry but using the fields from an older entry?

```
public function update($id){
    $updated_user = new User; // Create new user
    $user = User::find($id); // Find previous user entry

    $updated_user->id = $user->id; // Grab old ID (if you want the same ID as last entry)
    $updated_user->username = Input::get('username'); // Update username/password
    $updated_user->password = Input::get('password');
    $updated_user->userid= $user->userid; // Grab other attributes from old user entry

    $user->delete(); // Delete old entry
    $updated_user->save(); // Save new one
}
```

Comment: I didn't need to update my table schema. I need to update table data.while update a table data i need to delete its current existence and add the edited values as a new data. Is their any easy way in laravel like softdelete

Comment: Ok, but you did state that you wanted to update your 'model' by deleting it's current existence and creating a new one with updated fields. I've updated my answer, let me know if it's what your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Eloquent model to enable soft deletes.

```
   protected $softDelete = true;
```

You can see examples of how they work: [Soft delete](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting) in Laravel.

Comment: I need to update table data.while update a table data(row) i need to delete its current existence and add the edited values as a new data(row). Is their any easy way in laravel like softdelete.

Comment: Use Events http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events, when the updating event is fired, delete it and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a soft delete in Laravel as far as i know. Main reason is surely because soft delete has no strict definition - its up to the developer how you decide to implement and carry out a soft delete

What you can do instead is add a column to your table to mark if the row is 'deleted' or not. Updating then becomes easy as you set the status of the column to 'deleted' (or however you want to implement soft delete) for the existing model, and then just create a new model using the updated values

```
// set status of existing model to 'soft delete'
$existing_model->delete_status = 1;

$existing_model->save();

// create a new model with updated values
Your_Eloquent_Class_Model::create($array_of_updated_values);
```

Comment: There is softdelete in laravel. http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: ah cool! Didn't know that. Im still on L3 - is this new to L4?